# Error while doing writing unit test case -Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0

Tags: c#, oracle, unit-testing, nunit

We have a requirement to do unit testing using either MS Test or NUnit Framework for our C# code. There are many methods which includes DB call. When trying to do so, I am getting below error:

***{"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*******' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."}***

I checked the Oracle version to make sure there is no mismatch, but no success. Also read couple of articles that instead of making DB call one should be using mocking to bypass DB. But with this limitation the coverage is very minimal.
Could anyone please guide to fix the above error. Adding the sample code which i tried just for POC

```
public class Class1
    {
        public IEnumerable<ModelClass> GetListOfExceptions()
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Constants.ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Constants.<Oracle Query>, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ModelClass modelException = null;
                List<ModelClass> lst = new List<ModelClass>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    modelException = new ModelClass();
                    modelException.POLICYNO = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1));
                    modelException.PREMIUM = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(2));
                    modelException.AGE = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(3));
                    lst.Add(princeException);
                }
                return lst;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }


    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void GetListOfExceptionsTest()
        {
            Class1 obj = new Class1();
            obj.GetListOfExceptions();

        }
     }
```

Comment: Check that your test project target format is the same as the Oracle reference (x86 vs x64)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the ODP.NET (i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess`) is not installed on your machine. Or maybe it is installed but you did not install any Oracle Client (e.g. Oracle Instant Client)

Go to this page [Oracle Data Access Components - .NET Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html) and download and install the *Oracle Data Provider for .NET*. Ensure that you download the same version as your Oracle Client in case you installed already one. Ensure also that you have the same architecture, i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit as your application.

Comment: Thank you for the response but seems ODP.NET is already installed, as I am getting the error only while executing the test case.

Comment: What about the compile target? (32 vs. 64 bit) Does it load `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` from GAC?

Comment: The Oracle.DataAccess.dll is loading from below path: C:\oracle\product\12.1.0.2\ODP.NET\bin\4\4.112.4.0

Comment: Are you sure? Try `Console.WriteLine(conn.GetType().Assembly.Location);`

Comment: @JainPrince, could be a version mismatch. According to your path, the Oracle Client is version 12.1 whereas the ODP.NET version is 11.2 - they have to match!

Comment: Finally this issue is resolved with installation of Oracle Client 12.1 (32 version)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue is fixed after installation to Oracle Client 12.1 (32 bit version).